# I'm kind of new to this creatine protein stuff, and need help

Tags: diet, workout, protein, creatine

My schedule consists of me working out in the morning, around 7 am, eating 2 eggs before that cooked. after my workout I take my protein/creatine in the same bottle. Should I take it around supper too? I workout during the weekdays.  I need to know what I should be doing also to go from 160 to 180 in 4 months.

Also should I be switching my diet going from drinking pop and stuff to lean meats and protein foods with carbs? I heard from many people but they all have different strategies and it doesn't help.  Is there anything else I should take?

Comment: Your question is very poorly formulated, so its hard for me to understand what you're trying to achieve and I fear you don't really know either. What kind of workouts do you do and what do you expect creatine or protein to do for you?

Comment: Sorry, new to this. I'm 17. My workout program has me doing 
Monday
Back Squat
Hang Clean
 5 reps 3 sets 60%, 70%, 80% of my weights. The last one is go til fail.
3x10 accelerated jumps
3x20 abs
Tuesday 
Same rep/sets
Bench 
Bentover row
Bicep curls
3x10 pullups
Wednesday 
Some kind of cardio for an hour
Thursday=monday
friday= tuesday

I want to boost my muscle mass as well as increase maxes.

Comment: So what is the goal of your workout? Bulk up and get more muscle? And **why** do you think you need creatine or protein to reach this goal and not just a healthy diet?

Comment: So what are your goals?  If you don't have a destination, you can go any direction to get there.

Comment: I'm 18 years old and I've noticed a lot of my friends taking it and they seem to be having results.  I know most of it is hard work, im trying to bust my balls everyday

Comment: I'm going to recommend a book. It's the only book that's simple enough that even I can follow it: http://www.amazon.com/Body-Life-Mental-Physical-Strength/dp/0060193395. It's a great book, if you read it and follow the instructions in it.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to eat does also depend on your body type (and age).  Definitely you'll need protein, the basic building blocks of muscle.   You'll want more than one serve per day.  Go for at least another in the evening, as well as more lean meats.  Try to eat protein with every meal.

Also, don't ignore carbs.  You need carbs for energy to fuel your workouts and also to ensure that the protein you intake is not being used for fuel and remains for muscle building.

Depending on the type of creatine/workout booster your taking, I expect you'll get more benefit taking that prior to your workout, rather than immediately after. Creatine aids in energy transfer **during** anaerobic activity, such as a weight training. It's not a supplement for directly building muscle, as protein is.

Importantly, lift hard and go to failure and beyond with every set (once your form is good).  Your body only grows in response to stimulus and that stimulus is making it work harder than it is used to working.  Even if that means increase the weight by only a 1lb each workout, or doing one more rep to failure.

Comment: **There is no advantage to taking creatine before a workout**. It takes a very long time for creatine to be stored in the muscles. Before it reaches the muscle, creatine is useless. You can take creatine the day before a workout and it should be ready by then. 6 Time Mr. Olympia, Dorian Yates, actually suggests taking creatine with protein and simple sugars *after* your workout as that is the time when the muscles are absorbing nutrients at an accelerated rate. He talks about creatine at [9:40 in this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W25lLg2DxGM).

Comment: hmm true.  when i'd take nothing but creatine I used to load.  for the last few years I've been using this http://www.urbanmuscle.com.au/ProductDetails.asp?ProductCode=INCEL&Show=ExtInfo which contains a lot of creatine and is recommended for consumption shortly before working out.  probably because of the ingredients that aren't creatine.

Answer (score 1):

Your training program looks good, ideally if you want to gain mass then you should focus on compound exercises (never compromise on form however) and as anyone will be able to tell you 80% of you gains will depend on your diet.

Use [this calculator](http://www.freedieting.com/tools/weight_gain_calculator.htm) to figure out how many calories you need to intake per day.

Regarding the actual diet, definitely cut the soda. Focus on lean meat and a high protein diet. You will have to ask a nutritionist to make you a diet depending upon your tastes and schedule. What worked for me was a lot of sausages, potatoes, pasta and burgers along with the obvious lean chicken, but then I didn't care about gaining fat as I was pretty skinny :)

To answer your question though, creatine gives you a strength boost and one serving a day is enough, you could consider adding a serving of mass gainer before you hit the sack.

Answer (score 1):

Besides your protein intake, you need to cut "empty calories" (ie sugars) as much as possible if you want to build lean mass, and not gain fat.

A can of pop has about 140 calories.  Sure you need calories to live, but the reason it's called "empty" is because *besides fuel your body for the day*, that "food" (Coke) doesn't do anything else for your body.

Better have 140 calories of *some food* (any food!) that has at least some kind of vitamin/mineral content.